# Node.js HEAD http request

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers

I want to just check if http file is available, how do I request only headers with Node.js?

```
http.head("http://domain.io", (res)=>{
   console.log(res.statusCode)
})
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

```js
'use strict';

const http = require('http');

http.request('http://example.com', { method: 'HEAD' }, (res) => {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
}).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
}).end();
```